# Function was not declared in scope (GLFW, OpenGL, Slackware)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my first GL simple program with g++ on Linux using:

> -lxcb-dri2 -lxcb-lm -ldl -lXrender -ldrm -lXdamage -lX11-xcb -lxcb-glx -dri3 -l-L/usr/local/lib -lrt -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXcursor -lGL -lm xcb-present -lglfw -lxcb-sync -lxshmfence -lXxf86vm -lXfixes -lXext -lX11 -lpthread -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lGLEW

and I've got this error:

```
graphics/window.cpp: In member function 'bool je::graphics::Window::init()':
graphics/window.cpp:55:32: error: 'key_callback' was not declared in this scope glfwSetKeyCallback(m_Window, key_callback);
```

My code is in three files.

main.cpp:

```
#include "graphics/window.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace je;
    using namespace graphics;

    Window window("just engine", 800, 600);
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    while (!window.closed())
    {
        window.clear();
        if (window.isKeyPressed(GLFW_KEY_A))
        {
            std::cout << "PRESSED!" << std::endl;
        }

        glDrawArrays(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 6);
        window.update();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

window.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

namespace je{ namespace graphics{

#define MAX_KEYS    1024
#define MAX_BUTTONS     32

    class Window
    {
    private:

        const char *m_Title;
        int m_Width, m_Height;
        GLFWwindow *m_Window;
        bool m_Closed;
                static bool m_Keys[MAX_KEYS];
                static bool m_MouseButtons[MAX_BUTTONS];
                static double mx, my;
    public:
        Window(const char *name, int width, int height);
        ~Window();
                void clear() const;
        void update();
                bool closed() const;

        inline int getWidth() const {return m_Width; }
        int getHeight() const {return m_Height; }

        static bool isKeyPressed(unsigned int keycode);
        //friend void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
    private:
        bool init();
        friend void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
    };
}}
```

window.cpp:

```
#include "window.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

namespace je{ namespace graphics {


    bool Window::m_Keys[MAX_KEYS];
    bool Window::m_MouseButtons[MAX_BUTTONS];
    double Window::mx;
    double Window::my;
    void window_resize(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);
    Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height)
    {
        m_Title = title;
        m_Width = width;
        m_Height = height;
        if (!init())
            glfwTerminate();


        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_KEYS; i++)
        {
            m_Keys[i] = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUTTONS; i++)
        {
            m_MouseButtons[i] = false;
        }
    }

    Window::~Window()
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    bool Window::init()
    {

            if(!glfwInit())
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_Width, m_Height, m_Title, NULL, NULL);
        if (!m_Window)
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            std::cout << "Creating window failed." << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_Window);
        glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_Window, this);
        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, window_resize);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(m_Window, key_callback);

        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Could not initialize GLEW!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

                std::cout << "OpenGL " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

        return true;
    }

        bool Window::isKeyPressed(unsigned int keycode)
    {
        if (keycode >= MAX_KEYS)
            return false;
        return m_Keys[keycode];
    }


    void Window::clear() const
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    void Window::update()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(m_Window, &m_Width, &m_Height);
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_Window);
    }

        bool Window::closed() const
        {
                return glfwWindowShouldClose(m_Window) == 1;
        }

    void window_resize(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

        void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        Window* win = (Window*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
        win->m_Keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
    }
} }
```

I'm really beginner and I'm lost in it... Could You help me find a way? Thank You.

Comment: You key_callback(...) is an member function, you can't use it as an argument. You should either create an wrapper or define it as static or simply define it outside the class.

Comment: please consistently indent the code.  Do not mix tabs and spaces when indenting.  place 2 or 3 (be consistent) blank lines between functions for readability.

Comment: Looks like you are programming in C++ and not C.  The C language does not have classes, constructors or destructors.  I recommend you adjust the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the C++ member function `void key_callback()`, as a parameter to the C-implemented library function `glfwSetKeyCallback()`, you should declare it as `static`, but outside of the class declaration first. So try something like this for your **window.h**.

```
class Window;
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

class Window {
    private:
        // fields here

    public:
        // other member functions here

    private:
        friend void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
};
```

And then in **window.cpp**:

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    Window* win = (Window*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    win->m_Keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
}
```

I haven't written in this glfw library, so my answer might not be sufficient for your purposes. Have a look at these questions: [Pointing to a function that is a class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676971/pointing-to-a-function-that-is-a-class-member-glfw-setkeycallback) , [Is it possible to declare a friend function as static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845478/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-friend-function-as-static)

Comment: Thank You so much! Editing only window.h worked for me.